# iOS build size is too large in Unity

Tags: unity, ios, scripting, build-process

I have finally completed my game and ready to upload my game to the App store, but my build size is too large.

I have checked log statement and it is roughly **13.3 mb** but when i build my game and test on iOS device it is **80.0 mb**.

[image]

Also

`Scripting Backend` is 'Mono2x'

`Stripping Level` is 'use micro mscorlib'

`Script Call Optimisation` is 'Fast but no Exception'

My Game size must be around 15 to 20 mb why it is too large?

What i am missing?

Comment: A unity iOS project with nothing in it is over 50 MB. The player is huge. Unity is an engine that has a player for each platform, and the build process dumps out a data chunk the player uses to make your app work.

Comment: @Almo how can i figure out that what will be my app size in App Store? or should i upload it with  **80.0mb**?

Comment: It's tricky, and I don't really know how to do it. With the new BITCODE thing, after they get it, they may recompile the BITCODE on their end, and it will end up smaller. I think my game Cognizer ended up 5-10 MB smaller after they did that.

Comment: This is the problem with unity. It outputs HUGE files.

Answer (score 3):

There is a unity guide for general optimisation on the [unity website](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html).

To summarize it quickly (read the article):

- Reduce texture sizes (You can have specific settings Just for IOS)
- Compress meshes and animation
- Remove any DLLs that the platform your building for doesn't use
- Reduce .NET API size (player Settings->IOS->Other Settings->Api Compatibility Level Set to ".NET 2.0 Subset")

You can see the larger assets in that image you linked above, Look at those and make sure that you compress them appropriately for IOS (see the [unity website from above for a guide on that](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html))

Note there is a great question that might help you [here about the web player being too large](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/153065/file-size-is-far-too-big.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to ask that the `Textures` is only 3.8 mb which is already compressed i think? as it is only 3.8 mb.

Comment: how can i remove DLLs files that take up to `29.5%`?

Comment: Look though your code and remove all "using" lines that don't contribute to code. So system, generic collection, etc (assuming you don't use them)

Comment: @user3191102 i have removed the "using" lines and it helps to reduce little size of the build.., but my application is still 75mb on the device. what can i do about that?

Comment: I don't know, look at other games that are similar to your and see how big they are, if there around the 80mb mark then that is probably as good as your going to get it. Maybe look at asset bundles to make your game look smaller than it actually is....